# Java String Equals not working for UDP server received packet

Tags: java, udp

Here are simple UDP client-server classes:

UDPServer:

```
import java.net.*;
/**
 * Source:https://systembash.com/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/
 * 
 */
class UDPServer {    
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {            
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9876);            
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];            
        while (true) {            
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);

            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);                
            String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());                 

            // Sentence here is not equal "PING" ?
            if(sentence.equals("PING")) {                       
                System.out.println("It is PING: " + sentence);          
            } else {
                System.out.println(sentence.getClass());
                System.out.println("It is not equal PING. It is <" + sentence + ">");
            }                          
            System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);

            InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();                
            int port = receivePacket.getPort();                
            String capitalizedSentence = "PONG"; 
            sendData = capitalizedSentence.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket sendPacket
                    = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
            serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
        }
    }
}
```

UDPClient:

```
import java.net.*;
/**
 * Source:
 * https://systembash.com/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/
 *
 * @author  
 */
class UDPClient {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {       
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();        
        InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");        
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

        String sentence =  "PING";
        sendData = sentence.getBytes();

        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 9876);
        clientSocket.send(sendPacket);        
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
        clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);        
        String modifiedSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
        System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence);        
        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

In the UDPServer there's a check for the response (variable sentence). For some reason the equals doesn't detect the "PING" when it has to. Moreover it outputs the sentence string is "PING", class string. 
Why is that ?

The output of the UDPServer is the else:

```
class java.lang.String
It is not equal PING. It is:<PING>
RECEIVED: PING
```

If it matters the java version is "1.7.0_91".

Comment: I would String the length of data you have. I am guessing it not 4. Try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sentence.getBytes()));`

Comment: @PeterLawrey it isn't really. It is like [80, 73, 78, 71, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ... 0]

Comment: So it's not 4, but most likely 1024 and the nul character are not appearing which is why it looks the same but isn't.  You need to use the length of the message, not the whole buffer you get back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getData() gives you a buffer from which you can obtain your data.

Don't use trim() as this could remove characters you actually want to keep (apart from being expensive)

Instead you should use the length of the message

```
String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength());
```

This way you will only extract to portion of the buffer with data you want.

Answer (score 0):

The getData method of DatagramPacket returns the underlying buffer, which is the 1024 byte buffer you created earlier. You create a String from this buffer. All bytes not filled in will be 0 (default initialized), so your String will contain a lot of additional zero's. That's why the equals method returns false. You could solve this with the trim method if you're sure the messages sent will not have leading or trailing whitespaces (or at least, none that matter to the rest of the program).

Comment: No. It should be `new String(receivePacket,getData, receivePacket.getOffset(), receivePacket.getLength())`. There could be any arbitrary junk left in the byte array after the received datagram, and `trim()` won't remove that.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting true when calling equals because the response is 1024 bytes long. You can trim your response on UDPServer to solve this:

```
String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData()).trim();
```

Comment: No. It should be `new String(receivePacket,getData, receivePacket.getOffset(), receivePacket.getLength())`. There could be any arbitrary junk left in the byte array after the received datagram, and `trim()` won't remove that.